# Finding an integrating factor and solving the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I'm having trouble with this problem, and was wondering if someone could lead me in the right direction.

Here is the question. Show that $x^ay^b$ is an integrating factor of the equation
$$(b+1)x {dy\over dx} + (a+1)y = 0$$, and find its solution

My attempt:
$${dy\over dx}={-(a+1)y\over (b+1)x}$$
$${1\over (a+1)y}dy+{1\over (b+1)x}dx = 0$$
$A = {1\over (a+1)y}$, $B = {1\over (b+1)x}$
$${{dA\over dy}-{dB\over dx}\over B}={x(b+1)\over y^2(a+1)}+{1 \over x}$$
However, I'm kind of lost right now, where do I go from here, or am I even doing this right? Thanks

Comment: Multiply $x^ay^b$ to your equation then by using $\frac{dA}{dx}=\frac{dB}{dy}$ find $a,b$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(b+1)x {dy\over dx} + (a+1)y = 0\Rightarrow (b+1)x {dy } + (a+1)y dx = 0$$ 
let $N=(b+1)x, M=(a+1)y$ then $\frac{\delta N}{\delta x}=b+1, \frac{\delta M}{\delta y}=a+1$ so $$\frac{\frac{\delta N}{\delta x}-\frac{\delta M}{\delta y}}{M}=\frac{b-a}{(a+1)y}$$